# unexpected behavior from custom ObjectInputStream when reading object with LocalDate field

Tags: java, objectinputstream, localdate

i'm using the example from this repo https://github.com/kojenov/serial/tree/master/3-4.%20upload, which is presenting a method for specifying a way to protect form unsafe deserialization in Java by defining a custom ObjectInputStream and overriding a protected method **resolveClass** in which we have to specify which classes are allowed for deserialisation.
My problem is I added a **LocalDate** field to the **Planet** class and when I deserialize a serialized object I get this exception:

**invalid class except unsupported class; java.time.Ser**

I searched online and I could not find any other encounter with that problem, so I'm really confused. I tried with instead of the **LocalDate** to add a **LocalDateTime,** the same error happens again. As far as I found that class **java.time.Ser** is a protected class somewhere in the hierarchy of the classes in that package.
The class **LocalDate** is serializable, so this should not happen. I know for sure that the problem is in the **LocalDate**, because if I make that field **transient** code works as intended. Am I missing something or it's just a bug of Java Object Serialization?
By the way, the examples are originally from a talk given by Alexei Kojenov, his site is kojenov.com, but i couldn't find his email to ask him personally.

Comment: Maybe that example considered the java.time classes unsafe for deserialization? (Cannot guess the reason why, though. As you said, they are serializable.)

Comment: I don't think that the example has anything to do with the specific java.time package. If you look at the custom ObjectInputStream it basically checks if the object is of some classname, not checking any of it's member data. So again, what is happening here :D

Answer (score 1):

Serialization is recursive progress, which means when you're serializing a complex object, firstly you need to serialize all its properties. The same thing happens with deserialization.

`Planet` object contains fields of type `int`, `double` and `java.lang.String` which are primitives and don't need special (de)serialization. `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime` aren't primitives and they're serialized and then deserialized with `SafeObjectInputStream`.

#### Serialization hack

As it said in `java.io.Serializable` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Serializable.html), objects can modify their serialization behaviour and even delegate serialization to another class by defining method `writeReplace`.

JavaDoc cite:

> Serializable classes that need to designate an alternative object to be used when writing an object to the stream should implement this special method with the exact signature:

> `ANY-ACCESS-MODIFIER Object writeReplace() throws ObjectStreamException;`

> This writeReplace method is invoked by serialization if the method exists and it would be accessible from a method defined within the class of the object being serialized. Thus, the method can have private, protected and package-private access. Subclass access to this method follows java accessibility rules.

Both `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime` utilizes this possibility and define `writeReplace` method.

As an example, `java.time.LocalDate`'s implementation:

```
private Object writeReplace() {
    return new Ser(Ser.LOCAL_DATE_TYPE, this);
}
```

`java.time.Ser` is a package-private final class that is used as a delegate for `java.time.*` objects.

Hereby, when you're serializing `java.time.LocalDate` or `java.time.LocalDateTime`, actually `java.time.Ser` being serialized.

#### Custom deserializer

Previously we found out that `java.time.LocalDate` was serialized as `java.time.Ser`. Now, let's try to deserialize it with `SafeObjectInputStream`.

Before deserialization, `resolveClass` method is called:

```
@Override
protected Class<?> resolveClass(ObjectStreamClass input)
                                throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
  if (!input.getName().equals(Planet.class.getName())) {
    throw new InvalidClassException("Unsupported class", input.getName());
  }
  return super.resolveClass(input);
}
```

It checks for class name to be equal to `Planet.class.getName()`, but `java.time.Ser` is not, that's why you're getting an exception.

#### Solution

To resolve this issue, you need to add `java.time.Ser` to the list of trusted classes. I would suggest modifying your `SafeObjectInputStream` next way:

```
public class SafeObjectInputStream extends ObjectInputStream {

  private final List<String> supportedClasses = List.of(Planet.class.getName(), "java.time.Ser");

  public SafeObjectInputStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    super(inputStream);
  }

  @Override
  protected Class<?> resolveClass(ObjectStreamClass input)
                                  throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
  {
    if (!supportedClasses.contains(input.getName())) {
      throw new InvalidClassException("Unsupported class ", input.getName());
    }
    return super.resolveClass(input);
  }
}
```

**NOTE**: `List.of` was introduced in Java 9. If your Java version is less than 9, you can replace it with `Arrays.asList`.

Comment: Yeah, that works. I wanted to try the same, but I couldn't get around the way that `java.time.Ser` is not accessible to get it's name, but I guess your approach is kind of hack around that, to just define the class name as a string(ok, after all we are comparing strings in the if statement). I'm wondering whether or not the author of the solution Kojenov would approve this as a valid solution. Thank you for your great and succinct explanation of the delegation the serialization mechanism, because even though I found out the same stuff I couldn't understand it fully.

Comment: As I mentioned in answer, `java.time.Ser` is package private class, so you can't access it from your code (unless your code not placed in java.time package, which I don't recommend doing). String reference for a class is fine, since it allows to avoid hardcoding allowed classes and take out class names to external configuration (e.g. configuration file or JVM properties)

Comment: However this solution is not exact. Maybe because the way serialization is recursive and we only specify a whitelist for the top level class, if we want to have a member of type `Set`, then again due to the delegated serialization of the collection we have to specify (!) the exact implementation(let's say HashMap) and some nested delegated `java.util.CollSer` and  again it's possible to do the attack Kojenov proposed with the infinite recursive `Set`. I found a way to use Set as member data but it has to be constructed by using the factory method `Set.of()`, which returns immutable collection.

Comment: The reason to create whitelist is deserialize only classes **you trust**. So, `Set` is just an interface, it can have a lot of implementations. Somebody can implement their own set which will contain malicious code. That's why you need to whitelist **implementations** only. Filtration, provided in your example is very basic, it can be modified to use not only `ObjectStreamClass#getName` for filtration but other fields. Also, name filtration can be also adjusted. Actually, I don't know who Kojenov is and I'm not sure I can provide a solution he will accept.